# How do you say "to ask for" in Japanese?

Tags: words

How do you say "to ask for" in Japanese?.  For example:

> He asked his boss for a raise.
>
> We ask for great revival.

Is "仰{あお}ぐ" fine?  In particular, I want to use something that's natural and normal, but that's not disrespectful to superiors.  Some of the usual sources, like jisho.org, don't seem to be very definitive about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most normal word choice for "to ask for" is [頼]{たの}む.

仰{あお}ぐ means "to ask for" only in the sense of seeking guidance from someone above you -- not in the sense of asking for a raise.